# Can you add non-breaking spaces to an RTF file using WordPad?

Tags: rtf, whitespace, wordpad

I can't find a way to add non-breaking spaces to an RTF file using WordPad.

It is possible to do this in other editors (full Word, for instance) or by editing the RTF file directly as a text file.

([Explained here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch01.html): by using the `\~` escape string).

The closest I have come so far is to insert a non-breaking space into the RTF using one of these other means, and then copy/paste it within WordPad; this works. But I don't see a way to generate the NBSP character in the first place using WordPad. The other method is somewhat tedious and also error prone, because its not 100% clear that the character you're copying is indeed the NBSP in every case.

Comment: Doesn't typing Alt+0160 work for you? (with numlock on) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods

Comment: @Berend that's a good suggestion but I'm not in the habit of that approach because I have a tenkeyless keyboard which has no num lock key (not even using Fn). But it could be a good answer in general.

Comment: Oh, ok. Perhaps the onscreen keyboard can do it too, but I doubt it will be easier than what you do now. I think your best bet would be to use either 'charmap.exe', or some kind of macro using AutoHotkey or WinCompose or the like.